# Refreshing values from database to Combobox without adding twice the same values

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I can get the values from a certain columns(customer last name and first name) from my database into my combobox in my mainform and it's already loaded when the form is opened using LoadEvent. However I have another form where I insert another row (customer lname, fname, phone, etc.) on the same table as where my column is shown on the mainform. So I decided to put a button on my mainform where I can refresh the content of my combobox when I added a customer using the other form. The problem is when I press the button to refresh it only creates a duplicate of what already is on the combobox plus the other 1 that has just been recently added. Please help.

My code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-39SPLT0;Initial Catalog=SalesandInventory;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select clName, cName from tblCustomer", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            sda.Fill(ds);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + ", " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);

            }
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Is there a way to `Clear` the `comboBox1` or its `Items`?

Comment: @mjwills I'm not sure, what I know is only clearing the selected Item. comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;

Comment: better way is possible, look my answer!

Comment: The result is ok, in your for loop, you add to your combobox all items who is in your db. But you don't clear previous result. That's mean each time you call this code, you will add to your combobox all items. Try to put this before your for loop : 'comboBox1.Items.Clear()'

Comment: @PurTahan thank you but I'm not sure how to implement your advise. But thanks man. I already see another workaround though.

Comment: @mole yeah that's what I did and works. Since I I made the code as a function I can easily call it on my clear button and added the code you said. So it's comboBox1.Items.Clear(); followed by CustomerInfo();(Which I made as a function). Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You can just this code instead yours :

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.ValueMember = "clName";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "cName";
```

Comment: thanks man, I think this is good but I just don't know how to implement it and just added the comboBox1.Items.Clear(); as mole and mjwills said.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I feel silly but thanks to mjwills and moles.

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
CustomerInfo();
}

void CustomerInfo()
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-39SPLT0;Initial Catalog=SalesandInventory;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select clName, cName from tblCustomer", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            sda.Fill(ds);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + ", " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);

            }
            con.Close();
}
```